# Auto suggest chrome:// URLs in Firefox

Tags: firefox, history, xul

How can I enable auto-suggestions for chrome:// URLS in Mozilla Firefox, just as is done for http:// or file:// URLs?

Comment: What do you mean by "auto-suggest" exactly?

Comment: When you start typing a URL into the location bar, Firefox offers you a list of dynamically fetched completions. However, it works only for common URI schemes such as http:// or file://, but not for chrome:// URLs which would be useful if you're developing Firefox extensions. Its settings can be found at Edit > Preferences > Privacy > Location Bar.

Comment: I suspect this is not a function of the auto-complete feature itself, but rather due to the fact that chrome:// URLs are not stored in history. So perhaps there is a way to override that behavior.

Comment: @Fraser: [Don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46035/should-i-remove-tags-that-dont-contribute-to-categorizing-the-question/46037#46037) [tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43879/anti-tags-valid-use-or-not) [not-programming-related.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag/10222#10222)

Comment: Too bad we can't vote to close something that has a bounty.  This is not programming related.

Comment: It's something that would be helpful for Firefox extension developers. If Firefox is the platform that you're developing for, it is logical for you to be curious why that platform doesn't behave the way you think it should, and whether its behavior could be changed. If there were a way to change that behavior (which I guess there's not) then it would be helpful to those programmers.

Comment: Is it just me, or is it a little hypocritical to claim that this question doesn't belong on the site, and then submit an answer to it anyway, thus getting 50+ reputation from it?

Comment: @MatrixFrog, I don't think it is programming related and I like to help people. What is hypocritical about that?

Comment: Okay, I guess that's fair enough. I take it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in Firefox goto;

"tools -> options -> privacy -> location bar"

Make sure that bookmarks are included in the auto-suggestions. Now simply bookmark the "chormes" you wish to have added to the auto-suggestions.

To do this browse to the desired chrome, such as "chrome://fireftp/content/fireftp.xul" and then bookmark the page by pressing Ctrl+D.

A second way would be to manually edit the formhistory.sqlite file for your profile and to add entries as desired.

Comment: That works, even though it's a solution that requires work on the side of a user. And, just to clarify, in linux distribution of Firefox, you have to go to "Edit -> Preferences -> Privacy -> Location Bar".

Comment: Sorry you never indicated the OS you were talking about. As it effects user settings how else would you expect it to be set except by the user?

Comment: Just as Firefox stores standard http:// or file:// URLs that are accessed often, it should automatically store all the other types of URLs that you often type into the location bar, don't you think?

Comment: I guess, it certainly makes sense to me as they are something you navigate to they should appear in the navigation history.

Comment: I see this as more of a workaround (that I already use), would love to know how to tell Firefox to add them to the history.